# jmeter JSR223 groovy overwrite file

Tags: file, groovy, jmeter

I've created a new file to write some information:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
out = new FileOutputStream("myfilePathName", true);
String outAggr="";
out << outAggr;
out.close();
```

I need to overwrite it or clear it before to add new information (out << outAggr).
I don't want to create another file each time.

I've already tried to:

```
out < outAggr;
out < "";
```

but I got an exception

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite any existing contents, you can just do:

```
new File("myfilePathName").text = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

To override file you need to call [newWriter](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/heads-up-on-file-and-stream-groovy-methods), for example:

```
String outAggr="";
writer = new File(myfilePathName).newWriter("UTF-8", true)
writer.write(outAggr)
writer.close()
```

> newWriter() methods have been added. It's now possible to specify the encoding used to write files, and optionnaly to specify wether we're in append mode.